# How do I give each person in this list a raise

Tags: java

Need to use a for-each loop and the raise each person gets is 1000.

Would it be like this?

```
int raise = 1000;
for (Person i : people){
    people.add(raise, i);       
    }
```

im working with this

```
   public ArrayList<Person> people;
```

Comment: I'm not going to answer until I'm in the list!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**If what you want is to raise for example salary by 1000 for every person**, it would be more like:

1.Define a class.

```
public class Person {

    private int salary;

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public void raiseSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary += salary;
    }
}
```

2.Use `raiseSalary(int salary)` method on every `Person` in your for-each loop.

```
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
people.add(new Person());
for (Person person : people) {
    person.raiseSalary(1000);
}
```

Dont forget to import `java.util.*` in order to use `List` and `ArrayList`.

Read about for-each loop [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).

Answer (score 4):

I think it is more like this:-

```
int raise = 1000;
for( Person i : people ) {
   i.giveRaise(raise)
}
```

NOTE: I'm not sure what the api for the Person class is so I'm guessing that part.

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
for (Person i : people) { ... }
```

I *think* you meant for the loop to contain this:

```
i.add(raise);
```

The first line declares the variable `i` to be assigned in turn to each of the `Person` values in the list `people`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this:

```
for (People p: people) {
   p.increaseRaise(1000);
}
```

Here you iterate over each element in the list called `people`. The actual element is referenced by the variable `p`. So you need a method called `increaseRaise` in your `People` class.